# C: Why can I not initialize structs inside of arrays with curly brackets?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
struct coord {
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct coord vertices[4];
```

But when I do the following, an error occurs:

```
void setVertices(float x, float y) {
    vertices[0] = (struct coord) { x, y };
}
```

Why isn't this allowed in C? Is there another way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: That's an assignment, not an initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can initialize structs that way, actually. The IDE just lagged on its error-checking for several minutes, for some reason.